# How to handle oneSignal notification received

Tags: android, onesignal

I want to make notification count badge on toolbar icon. i use onesignal to get a real time notification. so everytime there is new notification, i will save the count to sharedPreference and show it to toolbar icon like picture below [image]

how to achieve this ?

so the main problem here is how to handle notification received from one signal?

this is my notif count sharedpreference class

```
public class NotifCountSession {

// Shared Preferences
SharedPreferences pref;

// Editor for Shared preferences
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

// Context
Context _context;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Sharedpreference file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "notif";

// User name (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String KEY_COUNT = "count";

// Constructor
public NotifCountSession(Context context){
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

public void saveCount(int count){

    // Storing value in pref
    editor.putInt(KEY_COUNT, count);

    editor.commit();
}

public HashMap<String, Integer> getCount(){
    HashMap<String, Integer> notif = new HashMap<>();
    // user name
    notif.put(KEY_COUNT, pref.getInt(KEY_COUNT, 0));

    return notif;
}

public void resetCount(){
    // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try below solution :

Initialize one signal on your activity with context :

```
   OneSignal.startInit(this)   
   .setNotificationReceivedHandler(new ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler(this))
   .init();
```

Now you can use context on your onesignal class :

```
 private Application application;

    public ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler(Application application) {
        this.application = application; //Done now you have a context

    }
```

Comment: And how you have declared application to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

According to [OneSignal Documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#section--notificationreceivedhandler-) Implement `OneSignal.NotificationReceivedHandler` inside your `Notification` class

Then use `setNotificationReceivedHandler(new NotifCountSession(this))` method where (usually Application class) you are initializing your `OneSignal` instance like below:

```
OneSignal.startInit(this)   
   .setNotificationReceivedHandler(new NotifCountSession(this))
   .init();
```

Comment: ady tried. then the problem is i cannot get any android context inside that notification class

Comment: @Prasetyo pass your application context through constructor